# OCAML tail recursive merge sort

Tags: ocaml, mergesort, tail-recursion

I have some code written in OCaml where I am trying to make a function that takes a list and sorts it via merge sort.

```
let rec msort ls =
   let rec split lst (l1,l2) = match lst with
   | [] -> (l1,l2)
   | h::t -> split t (l2,h::l1) in
   
   let merge l1 l2 =  
      let rec mergemerge l1 l2 acc = match (l1,l2) with
      | (_,[]) -> l1
      | ([],_) -> l2
      | [], [] -> acc
      | (h1::t1,h2::t2) -> if h1 < h2 then mergemerge t1 l2 (h1 :: acc)
      else mergemerge l1 t2 (h2 :: acc)
   in List.rev (mergemerge l1 l2 [])
  in 
let (l1,l2) = 
split ls ([],[]) in merge (msort l1) (msort l2);;
```

When I try to compile the code, it says "Stack overflow during evaluation (looping recursion?)." I am wondering how to change the body so that it does not infinitely recurse and wondering how and where I would add base cases to the body. Thanks!

Comment: See https://www.cs.cornell.edu/courses/cs3110/2019sp/textbook/data/tail_recursion.html

Answer (score 0):

Your function calls itself recursively no matter what the input list looks like. So this will cause infinite recursion.

As you say, you need to check for the base case.

The base case for this function is pretty easy to see: are there any input lists that are already sorted? Yes, the empty list and a list containing just one element are already sorted.

Add an `if ... then ... else` as the outermost expression of `msort`. It should test for the base case and return the obvious result in that case. In other cases it should do what it does now.